# Adobe Analytics Beacon debugging in Chrome Dev Tools GET vs POST

Tags: post, google-chrome-devtools, query-string, adobe-analytics

I recently upgraded my Adobe Analytics implementation from H27 to AppMeas served via Adobe DTM.

I usually debug my Analytics Beacon using Chrome Dev Tools which nicely parses the Query String Parameters for me for easy debugging:
[Chrome Dev Tools > Network Traffic > GET Request with QS Params parsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMPQE.png)

However, lately I've started to see the Analytics beacon pass as a POST which Chrome Dev Tools displays as a big "Request Payload" dump:
[Chrome Dev Tools > Network Traffic > POST Request with Payload NOT parsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFmrH.png)

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?  And is there a handy tool you can recommend which parses this payload nicely for me on the fly for quick debugging?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Adobe Marketing Cloud Pulse](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adobe-marketing-cloud-pul/ocdmogmohccmeicdhlhhgepeaijenapj) will show the POST requests, formatted

Comment: More recent versions of AppMeasurement + Marketing Cloud Service (VisitorAPI.js) introduced making POST requests when the request URL is too long for a GET request. So it happens when you have a lot of data being sent in a given Adobe Analytics request. As to why Chrome Network tab doesn't feel the need to format it like they do the GET request payload.. I dunno.

Comment: So helpful - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs across this problem again, there is a Chrome Extension called "DataSlayer" that will parse out both the GET and POST requests into their parameters -- appearing in a different tab called...dataslayer. 
Very useful. Also much better for copying and pasting data into a spreadsheet (versus copying from the Network tab).

Answer (score -1):

Try using the [Omnibug](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/omnibug/bknpehncffejahipecakbfkomebjmokl) extension for Chrome to debug the `POST` type tags.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).